# How to execute a function each time the slider is dragged?

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction

I've created a function `f` and a slider:

```
Slider[Dynamic[y],{1,4}]
```

How to execute/call `f` each time the slider is dragged?

Comment: Still no code formatting or capitalization in your original question (other people were kind enough to edit)...

Answer (score 10):

Like this

```
Slider[Dynamic[y,(y=#;f[y])&],{1,4}]
```

You can can test using for example

```
f[y_]:=Print@y;
```

I advise you to look at the help of [Dynamic](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dynamic.html) that contains examples of other related features.

Answer (score 4):

Another rout to take would be just using `Manipulate`. It will update content inside of it automatically in addition to automatically creating an interface.

```
f[y_] := y
Manipulate[f[y], {y, 1, 4}]
```

[image]

Comment: @user4972 What do you mean? Do you need more help?

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov He means that he registered the code above and got a patent for it. You're forbidden to use Manipulate[] again without his granting permission.

Comment: @belisarius big :D