# Dynamic Chart Elements in Bar Chart

Tags: plotting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to execute a function each time the slider is dragged?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16171/how-to-execute-a-function-each-time-the-slider-is-dragged)

This is my code:

```
v = {{1, 2, 4, 3, 6}, {9, 10, 40, 30, 20}, {20, 60, 17, 10, 18}, {50, 
    60, 20, 29, 10}, {100, 20, 10, 50, 54}};
q = {0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.2, 1};
f[{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}, ___] := 
  Rectangle[{xmin, ymin}, {q[[e]] xmax, ymax}];
function[]= Dynamic[
  Animator[Dynamic[e], {1, 7, 1}, 10, AppearanceElements -> False, 
   AnimationRepetitions -> r]]

Column[{Slider[Dynamic[y], {1, 5, 1}], 
  Dynamic@BarChart[v[[y]], BarOrigin -> Left, 
    ChartElementFunction -> f, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, Max[v[[y]]]*1.3}, {0, Length[v[[y]]] + 0.5}}, 
    Axes -> False]}]
```

function is being called at random times and transitional effect occurs.
but i want function to be called everytime slider is dragged.

Comment: sorry for the complex question format.
i want the bars of my BarChart to appear in a transitional format. As though they r growing and coming back to actual value.

Comment: @santhosh you mean like some of those javascript barcharts do?